# angular-ui-router blank page with index.html in URL

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I use angular 1.1.5 and ui-router. My Spring-based webapp is reachable at `http://mydomain:8080/webapp/app/index.html`

All the resource files are loaded, and when angular bootstrap the main module, the URL is changed to `http://mydomain:8080/webapp/app/index.html#/index.html` and the page is blank.

ui-router is configured as

```js
myapp
        .config(function($stateProvider) {
            $stateProvider
                    .state('layout', {
                        abstract : true,
                        views : {
                            "headerView" : {
                                templateUrl : 'partials/header.html',
                                controller : 'LoginController'
                            },
                            "navigationView" : {
                                templateUrl : 'partials/navigation.html',
                                controller : 'NavigationController'
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .state(
                            'layout.home',
                            {
                                url : "", // root route
                                views : {
                                    "contentView@" : {
                                        templateUrl : 'partials/content.html',
                                        controller : function() {
                                            console.log("Root URL");
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            });
```

I tried to create a plunker to show the issue but I did not succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Add `url:'/'` to the base abstract view.

```
.state('layout', {
    abstract : true,
    url:'/',
    views : {
        "headerView" : {
            templateUrl : 'partials/header.html',
            controller : 'LoginController'
        },
        "navigationView" : {
            templateUrl : 'partials/navigation.html',
            controller : 'NavigationController'
        }
    }
})
```